# unable to connect to local dockerized devpi container for pip install in another container without "--net=host"

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, devpi

I am running devpi in a docker container like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=devpi docker-container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm -p 3141:3141 --name devpi -v /devpi_data:/data -e DEVPI_PASSWORD='********' akailash/docker-devpi
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 2 devpi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It runs fine. I can access it via URL on the host as well as install packages from it as expected.

```
6f663ba131a1        akailash/docker-devpi   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:3141->3141/tcp   devpi
```

However, if I want to build another docker image installing packages from this container there is a ConnectTimeout. If I try a curl the connection times out after a while.

I can do a pip install if I use --net=host option as described in this [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13914) . However, I don't want to have to use host networking. I have tried 0.0.0.0:3141 as well as 172.17.0.1:3141 and I have the same results. Adding --ip=0.0.0.0 in the docker daemon service doesn't work for me. How can I access the devpi container from another container without having to use --net=host every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I need access to devpi only which building the docker images required in my docker-compose file, I used the host networking within the build context:

```
build:
  network: host
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
```

This helps access devpi correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `--net=host` then you need to open the ports on the machine that is running devpi to allow external clients to connect and use it.

The point is that, when you set the host network to docker it takes their own IP address and then it can bind as many ports you need on that IP address, but if you are not using it your computer is acting as a router for the container and applying a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to allow access the internet for outgoing traffic but denying incoming traffic.

Because of that if you don't want to use the host network you have to modify the firewall to add a destination NAT rule and allow the traffic to reach the service.

You have some good examples on how to allow ports on iptables [here](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html)

Comment: my devpi docker container as well as other docker containers are all running on the same pc